# Can't save checkbox value in meta with wp insert post?

Tags: php, wordpress, checkbox

I am trying to add checkbox value through add_post_meta but getting no luck..!
It is saved in database...but when I open the post in wordpress the checkbox isn't checked..!

So please take a look over my code and let me know if I am doing anything wrong :

```
require_once("../rabotavbaku/wp-load.php");
// Create post object
$my_post = array(
  'post_title'    => $job_title,
  'post_content'  => "<strong>İş barədə məlumat</strong> :</br>".$job_description."</br><strong>Namizədə tələblər :</strong></br>".$requirements,
  'post_type'     => 'job_listing',
  'post_status'   => 'publish',
  'post_author'   => 0,
);

// Insert the post into the database
$post_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post );

add_post_meta($post_id, '_company_name', $company_name, true);
add_post_meta($post_id, '_application', $email, true);
add_post_meta($post_id, '_job_location', 'Baku', true);
add_post_meta($post_id, '_job_expires', $expire_date, true);
// This one is that checkbox meta but it isn't working
add_post_meta($post_id, 'tax_input[job_listing_type][]', 2,true);
```

Comment: Where are those variables coming from? Are you sure a valid `$post_id` is returned?

Comment: @mevius : It's a long script but I just copied the part where it's posting..! the rest is Simple HTML DOM..!

Answer (score 0):

Try this Please look at this image for checkbox cheked. for example
[image]

```
<li><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="checkInt[]"><span>Economics</span></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" value="3" name="checkInt[]"><span>Science</span></li>
```

---

```
require_once("../rabotavbaku/wp-load.php");
    // get values for check boxes
    $check = $_REQUEST['checkInt'];
    $q1=implode(',', $check);

    // Create post object
    $my_post = array(
      'post_title'    => $job_title,
      'post_content'  => "<strong>İş barədə məlumat</strong> :</br>".$job_description."</br><strong>Namizədə tələblər :</strong></br>".$requirements,
      'post_type'     => 'job_listing',
      'post_status'   => 'publish',
      'post_author'   => 0,
    );

    // Insert the post into the database
    $post_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post );

    add_post_meta($post_id, '_company_name', $company_name, true);
    add_post_meta($post_id, '_application', $email, true);
    add_post_meta($post_id, '_job_location', 'Baku', true);
    add_post_meta($post_id, '_job_expires', $expire_date, true);
    // This one is that checkbox meta but it isn't working
    add_post_meta($post_id, '_checked',$q1);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer..! but let me make it clear to you...I don't want to get value of checked checkbox but rather I want just to save a post meta with it so that when I edit my post so that checkbox is showed checked on my right sidebar on post edit page..! I am scrapping data from another site and then posting it directly to wordpress there won't be any manual filling of checkboxes so that I can get value of checkboxes and then save it as post meta rather I want to add post meta directly..!